# Request Timeout in flask (408 Status Code)

Tags: python, apache, flask

i've received request timeout after 20 sec when upload file and "werkzeug.exceptions.ClientDisconnected: 400 Bad Request" error in server side when using request.files!
this code working correctly for less than 20 sec!

Comment: Check the max request timeout setting for apache.

Comment: ProxyPass timeout is 10000 and   ProxyTimeout is 10000 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, i use [dropzone](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone) and chunking file.